# Multiple commands using Plink and batch file for Cisco switch

Tags: batch-file, ssh, putty, cisco, plink

I am currently trying to write a script to change the location (snmp) of more than 200 Cisco switches.

My problem is that I can't run more than one command at once. I've made a batch file which connects to the switch automatically and reads a .txt file where the commands are listed. But no matter what I do the best result I got was that only the first command was executed.

**batch File:**

```
cmd.exe /c echo n | "Filepath(plink)" -ssh Switch Hostname -l Username -pw "Password" -m "txt File"
```

**txt File:**

```
conf t
snmp-server location test
end
wr
exit
```

I've already tried other delimiters in the txt-File like `;` `|` etc.
But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a known limitation of Cisco, that it does not support multiple commands in an SSH "exec" channel command.

Quoting section [3.8.3.6 `-m`: read a remote command or script from a file](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-m) of PuTTY/Plink manual:

> With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even put multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse, and cannot be expected to work on all servers. **In particular, it is known *not* to work with certain ‘embedded’ servers, such as Cisco routers.**

---

Though actually, your commands are probably not standalone top-level shell commands anyway. I guess that the `snmp-server` (and others) are *subcommands* of `conf t`, aren't they? So your code would not work, even if Cisco did support multiple commands on the "exec" channel.

For details, see [How to type commands in PuTTY by creating batch file?](https://superuser.com/q/1103873/213663)

You need to execute the `conf t` and then provide its subcommands to its standard input.

One way to do that is like this:

```
(
    echo snmp-server location test
    echo end
    echo wr
    echo exit
) | plink -ssh hostname -l username -pw password conf t
```

Comment: Thank you for your anser,

it works better, but I can still execute only one command at once. Is there any way to run multiple commands?

Comment: That's quite vague.  What "one command"? One top-level command or one subcommand or `conf t`? I do know know Cisco, so I actually do not understand your commands.

Answer (score 0):

If the above mentioned Cisco limitation doesn't affect this syntax:

```
SET /P USERNAME=Enter remote Username:
SET "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter remote Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
$BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)"" for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set PASSWORD=%%p
plink -t -pw %PASSWORD% %USERNAME%@Hostname "COMMAND1; COMMAND2; COMMAND3; ETC"
```

If the above mentioned Cisco limitation DOES affect the above syntax:

```
SET /P USERNAME=Enter remote Username:
SET "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter remote Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
$BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)"" for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set PASSWORD=%%p
plink -t -pw %PASSWORD% %USERNAME%@Hostname "COMMAND1"
plink -t -pw %PASSWORD% %USERNAME%@Hostname "COMMAND2"
plink -t -pw %PASSWORD% %USERNAME%@Hostname "COMMAND3"
plink -t -pw %PASSWORD% %USERNAME%@Hostname "Etc"
```

Barbaric, yes, but I think Cisco can be thanked for that ;) (This is un-tested as I don't have a cisco device to poke at, but theory should be sound)

Comment: When executing Plink only once (the first example), there's no need for such a complicated code to prompt for a password. Just let Plink prompt on its own. + When executing multiple commands on one host, you can use the syntax from my answer. Again, you won't need the complicated code for password prompt. And you won't be authenticating n-times to the server. Moreover as mentioned already, the OP has only *one* top-level command. The others are subcommands. So neither of your examples will actually work for OP (Cisco or not).